# Request synonym for uimapview tag to mkmapview

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I noticed that there is a [uimapview](/questions/tagged/uimapview) tag, which I presume should have a synonym to the [mkmapview](/questions/tagged/mkmapview) tag. I presume the intention of the [uimapview](/questions/tagged/uimapview) tag is simply an erroneous reference to the iOS MapKit framework class [`MKMapView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that makes sense. I've gone ahead and created the synonym.